# How to calculate how much horsepower is needed to negate wing tip vortices with a wing tip prop?

Tags: aerodynamics

How to calculate how much horsepower is needed to negate wing tip vortices with a wing tip prop?

I understand 80% of drag is at the wing tips.
Source: Xflaero software notes.

I understand NASA's X-57 boasts a 80% reduction in drag using wing tip propellers rotating contra to the vortice spin direction.

How do you caclulate how much HP is needed to "undo" those vortices?

Comment: Please link the source.

Comment: Or better yet, quote and link, so we can easily asses the validity.

Comment: "*Source: Xflaero software notes*": What is Xflaero? Did you mean [XFLR](http://www.xflr5.tech/xflr5.htm)?